# Smoke Generator does not work

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

When I try to run the smoke simulator in Blender 2.62 I get no smoke at all. When I attempt to render, the only output is a black screen.
What am I doing wrong here that is making the smoke simulation not render? 
Is it a mistake I made, or a problem with Blender version 2.62?

Comment: Can you be more specific, just saying something does not work isn't helpful, there could be several things wrong here.

Comment: Can you upload the .blend somewhere so it can be looked at? For what reason are you using 2.62?

Comment: I have set up a flow and domain mesh, I have created materials and textures but my voxel data does not work. I cannot get any effect out of the voxel data at all, also, on my smoke generator, on the flow panel my smoke colour box is missing. I am in blender render. I noticed that one of the post state that the shader effect shader is not in untill 2.69 or later is there a plugin that I can get. I have watched the tutorials on Youtube but nobody say's anything about later versions of blender being different regarding the smoke generator.

Comment: The material is applied to the Domain not the Flow object... which may not be obvious to some.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you managed to simulate the smoke, but you can't render it. The reason is probably one of two:

- You're using Cycles in a old Blender Version
- You're using Blender internal, but haven't yet setup a material.

If you're trying to use Cycles to render smoke, it is possible now. Volumetric shading (the shader that makes smoke) is initial supported since 2.71. (see [Release Log](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Cycles#Fire_and_Smoke_Rendering))

Setting up a smoke material is kind of difficult, so [read the docs](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Smoke/Material) if you want all the details (they also have some screenshots if you get lost).

Here's a quick rundown of how to create the material:

1. Make sure you're using Blender Internal.
2. Select *Volume* from the material type (right between wire and halo)
3. Set the density to zero (we'll be affecting the density with the texture)
4. Go to the texture tab and create a new texture.
5. Change the texture type to voxel data.
6. In the Voxel data panel, do two things:

   1. Set the file format to smoke
   2. Set the domain object with your domain object's name
7. Scroll down to the influence panel
8. Check *Density*, *Emission* and *Emission Color* and leave them all at 1.000.
9. Hit *Render!*

Comment: The material setup is indeed quite involved. With any mesh object selected, Object menu > Quick Effects > Quick Smoke will also set up the appropriate Blender Internal material.

Comment: @Charles, might want to phrase it "Here's a quick rundown of how to create the material for the Smoke Domain object:", unless i'm the only dummy that tried to setup the flow object :) And to brecht's excellent suggestion, if anyone is confused why it worked at first but then stopped after saving the blend file, just go to the Domain's Smoke Cache and click Bake.

Answer (score 4):

For a smoke simulation you need to setup your scene at least with a flow object and a domain. The flow object emits the smoke and the domain is the demarcation of the simulation.

[image]

The setup is as follows (all settings are default exept the highlighted *Flow* and *Domain*)

The outer cube (domain)

[image]

The inner cube (emitter)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was to select the 'Physics Properties' of the Smoke Domain, and click 'Bake Data'.  Without doing that no smoke appeared.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the exact same issue for hours upon hours and discovered the issue was something small and easily overlooked:

In the Texture tab, after you have changed the texture type to Voxel, go down to where it says Voxel data. Under here, you will see a field for Domain Object. If it looks like a cube with blank space to the right of it, click the blank space in the field and in the pull down, choose "Cube". The field should now say Cube, and your preview should show your smoke.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

After followed a few tutorials, it still didn't work. Finally, I found that another factor is Domain Object's texture mapping coordinates. For some reason, the default settings might not apply any coordinates to the object.

[image: Smoke need coordinate]

So, check it when things don't work even you have followed exactly those steps.

Another quick fix is to use "3D Views>Object>Quick Effects>Quick Smoke" as the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new blender user, had the same issue, I tried everything in most forums and what worked for me was changing my device from GPU to CPU in my render tab. Apparently GPU can't render smoke and fire. Forgive me if I'm wrong about that, I just tried it and it renders now.

Hope it helps