# Problem rendering multiple smoke textures

Tags: materials, smoke-simulation

I have figured out what was [wrong with the smoke](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/951/smoke-generator-does-not-work), I could render it but I could not see it but it was there just the same, thank you. Now when I try and render two different smoke colors they both come out the same. I have gone into the compositor and created two different settings but I cannot apply them, also when creating two separate domain boxes and two emitters they only take one setting. I have tried to put them on separate layers but this does not work either, I do not want to go into the video sequence editor as this is long. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Well, not very clear... Did you create 2 distinct materials for your 2 distinct smokes ? I recommend you to be more specific in your question... Send some screenshots, etc.

Comment: Yes I did create 2 distinct materials and 2 different smokes, I thought I'd make that clear when I wrote "and created 2 different settings in the composition node editor". Even with 2 different settings and 2 different colours, both smoke generators take on one colour.  I cannot get Blender to treat the 2 differently ie asign the composition node editors to the 2 seperate smoke generators.  Screen shots to follow........thanks

Comment: I still suspect that you are using shared datablocks. Make sure that materials are all single-user. All textures are single-user, and all smoke systems are single-user.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your materials or your textures or your caches are linked. You can check this by changing one setting for *Smoke A* and see if it applies for *Smoke B*. If so, then your issue is linking.

To get rid of the link, click the button with the number on it next to the material and texture. That should fix it.