# Why is my smoke simulation not showing up with the default renderer?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

As per the picture, the fire/smoke is not showing up with the blender internal renderer. Is this a common issue?

Are there any obligatory steps to make it show like it does in the preview?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/951/smoke-generator-does-not-work

Comment: Are you using *quick smoke*?

Comment: Yep. You probably haven't added a smoke material. See the link by @cegaton.

Comment: No, I'm not using Quicksmoke, I built the scene from scratch. Isn't the render suppposed to show up without any additional setup?

Comment: No, you need a smoke material

Comment: If this is a duplicate question, could we know which of the answers is considered to be the right one? No one seems to have been accepted on the linked duplicate question